# Upgrading the commons-lang-2.6.jar throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

[image]I have upgraded the version of commons-lang from 'commons-lang-2.6.jar' to 'commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar'. After deployment when I goes to test particular link it throws "SEVERE: >>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils".                                       I have upgraded the Jar for Swagger compatability. I am using ant build, all these dependencies are declared in 'build.xml' and libraries are added in lib folder.

Comment: One or more libraries references to the old version. Use an IDE like Eclipse to check the dependencies of other libraries.

Comment: Additional check some classpath definitions.

Comment: @reporter Can you tell me in Eclipse how to check the dependencies of other libraries? Is there such a way, which would tell us missed libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base package of Apache Commons Lang 3 is not `org.apache.commons.lang` anymore.

Provided that the error occurs in your own code, you have to replace it with the `org.apache.commons.lang3` package .

If it occurs in external libraries, either upgrade them to a version that uses Lang 3 (if it is possible), or you may have to also keep your older *commons lang* among the dependencies (as explained in the answer by Karol, the distinct packages will prevent possible conflicts anyway).

e.g :

[org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) in Lang 2.6

vs

[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in Lang 3

Answer (score 1):

`commons-lang3` is using `org.apache.commons.lang3` base package to avoid conflicts with previous versions of `commons-lang`. This allows both `2.X` and `3.X` to be used at the same time.

To update to `3.X` uou have to change the `import` in your code e.g. use

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Comment: Where do I change this import? As in, which file?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the commons-lang3 dont have the package that is is used in commons-lang2. The class StringUtils is in org.apache.commons.lang3. The package  org.apache.commons.lang dont exist in the commons-lang3.